# JPA2, JAX-RS: @PersistentContext, How to get EntityManager in a Facade constructor?

Tags: jpa, jax-rs, entitymanager

I have a JAX-RS web service that was generated by Netbeans.  There are non-abstract facade classes for the service's endpoints.  The persistence context is being injected into the non-abstract facade.  Everything is working well and I see my data being returned to Fiddler.

We are using DTOs and I am implementing an assembler pattern.  So, in the non-abstract facade's constructor, I am creating an instance of the assembler, and am passing the facade's entity manager instance into it.  Unfortunately, it seems that the injection of the persistence context has not happened before the facade's constructor has been called, so I cannot pass the entity manager instance into the assembler for its to use in mapping operations.  Kind of a chicken-before-the-end situation...  I cannot figure out how to make this work...  Is there some kind of post-constructor method that I can override and perform the initialization of the assembler and pass in the entity manager to it?  I'd really appreciate your help and suggestions.

Thank you for your time and ideas,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method marked with `@PostConstruct` annotation. Like this:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    // I'm called after all injections have been resolved
    // initialize some object variables here
    ...
}
```

In that method you can use both, object fields initialized in the constructor and passed by injection.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gas!  It works perfectly!  The thought of using an annotation did not enter my mind.  Cool, stuff! :)